# Unique radio button for a row and a column

Tags: angular, typescript

I have three rows of radio buttons, they look like this:

[image]

Is this possible to make it so a chosen button would be exclusive within a row and a column? It means that on this matrix only 3 buttons can be chosen at the most.

For example, when I choose **a2**, buttons within this row aren't chosen (**a1**,**a3**) and also buttons within this column are disabled(**b2**,**c2**) meaning that you can't choose on **2** column (it's taken).

Can you help me with that?

**Template**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
   <span *ngFor="let inner of item.titles">
     {{inner.label}}
     <input type='radio' name='{{item.name}}'>
   </span>
</div>
```

**component**

```
items = [
  {
    name: 'first',
    titles: [ {label: 'a1'}, {label: 'a2'}, {label: 'a3'} ]
  },
  {
    name: 'second',
    titles: [ {label: 'b1'}, {label: 'b2'}, {label: 'b3'} ]
  },
  {
    name: 'third',
    titles: [ {label: 'c1'}, {label: 'c2'}, {label: 'c3'} ]
  } 
]
```

[Plunker Link](https://plnkr.co/edit/9PYctlbg9E2jUmlHhGEF?p=preview)

Comment: Or perhaps I need checkboxes for that. Not sure.

Comment: I think checkboxes would be more user-friendly.   Imagine the scenario where your user has checked all their radio buttons and then wants to change their mind; the radio buttons would prevent them from doing this.

Comment: @BenCottrell Anyway, can you help me with this. I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I made an edit to your question. I added the `typescript` tag so we can get syntax highlighting. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the cleanest solution (it hasn't been refactored to eliminate a couple of redundant fields); it's just the first thing I managed to get working with 15 minutes of tinkering in a plunker window:

***Edit/Update*** The previous version using `ngModel` didn't seem to play nicely cross-browser so here's an updated snippet (+ [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/doGyCXSpbDAbrwtNcYML?p=preview))

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
      <div *ngFor="let item of items">
        <span *ngFor="let inner of item.titles">
          {{inner.label}}
          <input type="checkbox" name="{{item.name}}" 
                 (click)="onClick(item.row, inner, $event.target.checked)"
                 [disabled]="!inner.state && (rows[item.row] || columns[inner.column])">
        </span>
      </div>
      `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular'; 

  items: [] = [
    {
      name: 'first',
      row: 0,
      titles: [ 
        {label: 'a1', column: 0, state: false}, 
        {label: 'a2', column: 1, state: false}, 
        {label: 'a3', column: 2, state: false} 
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'second',
      row: 1,
      titles: [ 
        {label: 'b1', column: 0, state: false}, 
        {label: 'b2', column: 1, state: false}, 
        {label: 'b3', column: 2, state: false} 
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'third',
      row: 2,      
      titles: [ 
        {label: 'c1', column: 0, state: false}, 
        {label: 'c2', column: 1, state: false}, 
        {label: 'c3', column: 2, state: false} 
      ]
    } 
  ];

  rows: boolean[] = [false, false, false];
  columns: boolean[] = [false, false, false];

  onClick(row, inner, state) {
    this.rows[row] = state;
    this.columns[inner.column] = state;
    inner.state = state;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The result is impressive. You must be having a good problem-solving skills.

Comment: @BillyLogan I feel like there's room for improvement by replacing the fields named `column` and `row`, with a call to `array.indexOf` instead (else it just feels like a violation of the D.R.Y. principle..).   On the other hand maybe this way is clearer for someone reading this answer to see what's going on.   The concept is more important than the implementation!

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would make much more sense if user had a possibility to uncheck a checked option.

Comment: @BillyLogan I was about to say "it should already be possible to de-select options", but then realised I had only tested it in Chrome.  Testing in FireFox and Microsoft Edge show totally different behaviour.     I'm not sure whether there's a problem with the `ngModel` binding in those browsers or if they're handling the `click` event differently

Comment: @BillyLogan the `ngModel` seemed to cause some problems in different browsers - here's a slightly modified example

Answer (score 2):

You could use checkboxes, and Bootstrap to make things a little more dynamic.

I would use something like `[disabled]="items.selected.length <=3` in the radio tags, or wrap them in a form. That way the buttons become disabled when there's 3 or more selected items.

Here's [my fiddle](https://plnkr.co/edit/bbgpdrY3ZiPZNAdr8g9z?p=preview)

I did dump the columns of 3 to simplify the ngFor. It would be pretty easy to add back.

I'm a Java programmer most of the time, looking at the code I think that's a bit obvious. I created a Item class and gave it two variables: title and selected.

```
 export class Title{

  public label:string;
  public selected:boolean = false;
  constructor(label)
  {
    this.label=label;
  }

}
```

In the HTML I am using `(checked)` to fire a change when the box is selected. That calls a function that flips the selected value on the particular item, and increments a counter.

```
<input   type="checkbox" name="label"
    [disabled]="checkedItems>=3"
    (change)="checkItem(title)"
    [checked]="title.selected" >
```

The inputs will become disabled when the counter hits "3".

There is a shortcoming, once you hit 3 items, there is no going back. Smarter code would use the `[checked]` call to use a function that read the counter/array length and disallowed adding a new item. It would allow a already selected item to be unselected.